# How decrypt a file in nano text editor?

Tags: encryption, gpg, nano

I encrypted a text file in terminal using "gpg -c filename" and got "filename.txt.gpg" created in my file manager. I deleted the original unencrypted file.

Now I want to decrypt it in Nano so I can continue working on it. If, in a terminal, I do "gpg -d filename.txt.gpg", the file opens in terminal where I can read it, but do nothing else.

I want to open the encrypted file in Nano, and add data to the file in Nano.

I've tried every way I can think of, but not able to decrypt and open the file in Nano. Any ideas? Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gpg -d` just prints the file to standard output, but you can redirect the output to a file instead: `gpg -d filename.txt.gpg > filename.txt`. Or use the `-o outputfilename` option. Also, you can just run `gpg filename.txt.gpg`, which cause `gpg` to guess what you want, and in that case it decrypts the file to `filename.txt` (dropping the final `.gpg`).

Of course, note that when you decrypt the file on a regular filesystem, the OS may write it to the disk and removing the file afterwards will not clear remains of the file data from the disk. To avoid that, make sure to decrypt sensitive data only to RAM based filesystems.

On Linux, that would be the `tmpfs` filesystem. In some distributions, `/tmp` is a `tmpfs` by default. If it isn't, you can mount a new `tmpfs` simply with `mkdir /ramfs; mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /ramfs` (as root, change the ownership and permissions as required). Just mounting a filesystem doesn't mean that your files would be saved there, but a full discussion of safely handling sensitive data is outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thanks. The first way works, didn't try the "-o", but not the third way. The 3rd way just tries to re-encrypt the same file. But doesn't matter, first way works fine. After that, need to go into Nano and go to the file directory and open the NON-encrypted duplicate copy and edit text. Then save it via encryption and repeat if want to add more data or edit. Thanks again.

Comment: ...the one thing I don't like is that when I open the unencrypted file in Nano and go to edit, it doesn't contain the original file name and I have to retype the file name again; seems trivial, but would rather just save. Thanks again.

Comment: @themira, hmm, I have `gpg` 2.2.4 on Ubuntu, and `gpg filename.txt.gpg` gives `gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...` and then it asks for the passphrase and decrypts the file.

Comment: ~$ gpg ENCRYPTING.A.NEW.FILE.IN.NANO.gpg;;; 
gpg: AES encrypted data; 
gpg: gpg-agent is not available in this session;
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase;
File `ENCRYPTING.A.NEW.FILE.IN.NANO' exists. - -  Overwrite? (y/N);;;
When I add the ".txt" ending, it does change the output. The first output above is without the extension. With extension ------------  gpg ENCRYPTING.A.NEW.FILE.IN.NANO.txt.gpg;;;
gpg: can't open `ENCRYPTING.A.NEW.FILE.IN.NANO.txt.gpg'
:~$

Comment: In regards to your additional 'answer' notes, I am having trouble determining how to remove certain hidden files from the directory in Nano. The files are either locked or .swp. I think Nano created backups of them without me knowing it. If someone were to get on my computer, I do not want them to see the NAMES of any of my deleted files, regardless of content. Is this what you are referring to when you said to only decrypt to RAM filesystems, though you seemed to be more focused on the content, I'm guessing? Would you happen to know how to remove these items from the directory? Thanks.

Comment: @themira, no, I mean that if you do `gpg -d encrypted.gpg > plaintext.txt` in a directory on a regular filesystem (e.g. `/home`), the system may write the plaintext data on the disk (and probably does write, unless you remove the file really quickly). Even if you remove it later, the data can still be left lying on the disk, even though it isn't accessible through the filesystem. An attacker who gains access to your computer can pull the drive out and read the raw contents on another machine. That undermines the idea of encryption.

Comment: And yes, `nano` like other editors probably creates some temporary files. That's actually all the more reason to process files like that in dedicated parts of the filesystem, and also an argument for making `/tmp` encrypted or RAM-based.

Comment: Thanks. " if you do gpg -d encrypted.gpg > plaintext.txt in a directory on a regular filesystem (e.g. /home), the system may write the plaintext data on the disk".  ---------- To create the /tmp -- my ubuntu has a /tmp. Should I put the files in there and encrypt them? If no, and "mount a new tmpfs simply with mkdir /ramfs; mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /ramfs" - is that done solely thru the terminal, typing in "mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /ramfs" ? After hitting enter, anything else? When I save a libre office writer file, it saves to /home. Is that not good - leaving a trace later viewing? Thanks again.

Comment: @themira, I'm not going to go full-on into handling of sensitive data. Using full-disk encryption might be a good idea, though.

Comment: Thanks. But could you mention - is it safer to save my "txt" and "odt" files in the temp folder, even if the temp folder is not encrypted (though I will look online to see how to encrypt a folder/ directory). Thanks for the extended help!